# Vuex with components only update one way

Tags: vue.js, vuex

### Setup

I have a super-simple test app with two components (an `<h1>` and an `<input>`) and a vuex data store. The `<input.` is bound to the store data element `pageTitle` with `v-model`, and the `<h1>` displays `pageTitle` using double brackets. When I change the text in the input field, the value is changed in the store and all components (I can see that in the dev tools).

### Problem

However, when I change the value in the store directly in the console (using `store.state.pageTitle = 'something else'`, the `<h1>` updates, but the value in the text field does *not*. However, on initial page load, the input is correctly populated using the data from the store. I guess it's not receiving  updates from the store.

### Question

Why is my input field not receiving updates from the store and updating it's value?

---

## Code

#### Javascript

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        pageTitle: "My Vuex Thing"
    },
    mutations: {
        pageTitle(state,title){
            state.pageTitle = title;
        }
    }
});

const topsection = {
    template: `<h1>{{ pageTitle }}</h1>`,
    computed: {
        pageTitle(){
            return store.state.pageTitle;
        }
    }
};
const contentsection = {
    template: `<div id="content">
        Enter a page title: <input type="text" name="pageTitle" v-model="pageTitle">
    </div>
    `,
    computed: {
        pageTitle(){
            return store.state.pageTitle;
        }
    },
    watch: {
        pageTitle(val){
            store.commit('pageTitle',val);
        },
    }
};


var v = new Vue({
    el: '#vue',
    store,
    components: {
        topsection,
        contentsection
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="vue">
    <topsection></topsection>
    <contentsection></contentsection>
</div><!-- #vue -->
```

Comment: What happens if you change your computed `pageTitle` properties to `return this.$store.state.pageTitle`?

Comment: I just tried this on my local machine and I'm not able to reproduce it. Which version's of vue and vuex are you using?

Comment: @thanksd Maybe the problem is the using of `v-model` to a computed property which are generally getters. I think he sholud be using computed setter instead of watch property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `v-model="pageTitle"` where `pageTitle` is a computed property. Computed properties are by default getter-only, but you trying to bind the value by using `v-model`.

So what you need is a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

So your **contentsection** component should be like this:

```
const contentsection = {
    template: `<div id="content">
        Enter a page title: <input type="text" name="pageTitle" v-model="pageTitle">
    </div>
    `,
    computed: {
        pageTitle:{
            get: function(){
                return store.state.pageTitle;
            },
            set: function(newTitle){
                store.commit('pageTitle',newTitle);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

You do not need a watcher.

Here is the working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61eyztca/)

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. And actually, for the record, it had nothing to do with Veux. When I took out Vuex, I had the same problem with the components. Your solution solved it, thanks! I didn't know about using get and set this way.